# Is there a way to use AutoMapper for mongo c# projection expression when using aggregate()?

Tags: c#, mongodb, automapper

I'm trying to avoid doing manual mappings of my models to viewmodels while using mongo c# driver (v2.7.2) aggregation and projection.

Instead of doing the mapping for the projection manually

```
var projection = Builders<Model>.Projection.Expression(x => new ViewModel { 
   A = x.A, 
   B = x.B
   // ...more properties
});
```

i want to use AutoMapper to do the mapping

```
var projection = Builders<Model>.Projection.Expression(x => _mapper.Map<ViewModel>(x));
```

And in fact, this is working when i just use it on a find() operation like this

```
var result = mongoCollection
   .Find(Builders<Model>.Filter.Empty)
   .Project(projection)
   .ToList();
```

But when i use the same projection on aggregate()

```
var result = mongoCollection
   .Aggregate()
   .Project(projection)
   .ToList();
```

it's throwing an ArgumentOutOfRangeException

> Exception has occurred: CLR/System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
>   Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' in
>   System.Private.CoreLib.dll: 'Index was out of range. Must be
>   non-negative and less than the size of the collection.'

First of all i'd like to know why mapping with AutoMapper is working for find() but not for aggregate()?

And also if it is possible to use AutoMapper in this scenario somehow, or if there is some other way to map into the target class without explicitly deserializing the result client side?

Comment: You can try using the expression ProjectTo generates, but that's not a supported scenario as far as AM is concerned, so you're one your own.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Unfortnunately ProjectTo() is not supported by IAggregateFluent<TResult>.

Comment: Obviously :) But check [the execution plan](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Understanding-your-mapping.html).

Comment: Oh i see, but i'm afraid that this exceeds my expression knowledge... Can u give me an example how or where to wire this up?

Comment: Actually i can run something awkward like this, but this is throwing the same exception. 
var projection = Builders<Model>.Projection.Expression(x => _mapper.ProjectTo<ViewModel>(Enumerable.Repeat(x, 1).AsQueryable(), null).Expression);

Comment: Was this solved? I'm having the same problem!

Comment: @LTV Unfortunately not, didn't delve deeper into this.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe kinda late to the party, but I managed to integrate it. The problem with `var projection = Builders<Model>.Projection.Expression(x => _mapper.Map<ViewModel>(x));` is that it is a client side projection.

In order to use automapper for server side projections one has to convert the `IQueryable<T>` produced by automapper back to `IMongoQueryable<T>`.

My extension method:

```cs
public static class MongoDbExtensions
{
    public static IMongoQueryable<TDestination> ProjectTo<TSource, TDestination>(this IMongoQueryable<TSource> query, AutoMapper.IMapper autoMapper) =>
            query.ProjectTo<TDestination>(autoMapper.ConfigurationProvider) as IMongoQueryable<TDestination>;
}
```

usage:

```
private readonly IMongoCollection<Book> _books;
private readonly IMapper _mapper;
// ...
_books
            .AsQueryable()
            .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize)
            .Take(pageSize)
            .ProjectTo<Book, BookListDTO>(_mapper)
            .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: An alternative solution, however evading automapper completely, is this: https://tpodolak.com/blog/2019/10/22/mongodb-driver-class-based-server-side-projection/